# Htaccess subdomain redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to do this type redirection by .htaccess only:

from: `http://domain.com/directory.php?ref=sub`
to: `http://sub.domain.com/directory.php`

If not, what do I need for that?

Answer (score 3):

Check Tutorial

http://blog.gwebtools.com/apache-htaccess-subdomain-redirect-rules/

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.domain.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Replace both instances of "domain.com" with your domain name.